# Parsing jQuery formdata from Python

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, bottle, form-data

My app has a python (bottle.py) backend and an html/jquery frontend.
I am getting a text file using 'input' in a form and uploading it in background, using event handler on a python side. The event handler then parses the file (calling `file.readline()` repetitively) and returns some result in json form back.

Everything goes well until I need to parse the file in python.

Here is my javascript:

```
function UploadFile() {
    var file = $('#data')[0].files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'plates',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

When I recieve the POST request on the python side, I can read it only with `request.body.read().decode()`. If I am trying `request.files.data.file.read()`, I am getting the 'broken pipe' error:

```
socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I can just get the text with `request.body.read().decode()`, save them to file and then load it and parse. But I would like to avoid creating files that are not necessary to create, and want to do everything in memory.

Why does `request.body.read().decode()` work and `request.files.data.file.read()` doesn't?
Is there any way to parse the file with my existing function while not writing it to a disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest making sure that your request is submitted with the content-type "multipart/form-data". The default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", which might not be what bottle expects when trying to parse a file.

[RFC 2388](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388) is a good (albeit thick) source of information if you want to learn more about handling multipart forms in HTTP (including files)

Also, here's a [good discussion about file upload with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax).

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely no idea why the two calls are different (I use django), but the way you parse it without writing to disk is by getting a new BytesIO instance, writing to that, and using that in place of your file handle.  Just a partial solution.

If it is just text, consider using StringIO instead